# Export Records from CSV File With Current Month's Data

Tags: foreach, export-csv

I am trying to export records form a YTD CSV file that have records with the current month.  Example of data below.   I can not figure this out:

"3MCO","","00280916","04/24/2023","42105PB","X",2,"EA",328.14
"3MCO","","00280916","04/24/2023","42135N","X",10,"EA",2591.6
"6SPR","","00281007","04/26/2023","","X",1,"",0
"6SPR","","00281007","04/26/2023","41914","X",1,"DOZ",126.81

Any help would be appreciated.
rev.

I have tried Get-Date -Format MM, but I can't figure out the "IF forreach" parameters.

rev.